# Distribute small collection output to multiple workers using Apache Beam Python over Google Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline that looks roughly like this:

```
_ (
  p |
  SomeSourceProducingListOfFiles() |
  beam.Map(some_expensive_fn) |
  beam.FlatMap(some_inexpensive_agg)
)
```

*SomeSourceProducingListOfFiles* in my case is reading from a single CSV/TSV and doesn't currently support splitting.

*some_expensive_fn* is an expensive operation that may take a minute to run.

*some_inexpensive_agg* is perhaps not that important for the question but is to show that there are some results brought together for aggregation purpose.

In the case where *SomeSourceProducingListOfFiles* produces say 100 items, the load doesn't seem to get split across multiple works.

I understand that in general Apache Beam tries to keep things on one worker to reduce serialisation overhead. (And there is some hard coded limit of 1000 items). How can I convince Apache Beam to split the load across multiple workers even for a very small number of items. If I say have three items and three workers I would like each worker to execute one item.

Note: I disabled auto scaling and am using a fixed number of workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#preventing-fusion discusses ways to prevent fusion. Beam Java 2.2+ has a built-in transform to do this, `Reshuffle.viaRandomKey()`; Beam Python [doesn't yet have it](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1872) so you'll need to code something similar manually using one of the methods by that link.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't quite sure of the terminology. Not sure why I haven't tried group by / ungroup before but it seems to work. However, I understand it will materialise the whole list. That is acceptable in my case but I am interested in a solution that would also scale to large number. Will _reshuffle_ have a similar effect but would not require the collection to be materialised?

Comment: Both will materialize. Is there a reason you're particularly concerned about the cost of materialization? How much data will there be?

Comment: At the moment it's not much, less than 1000. In the future it might go up to 100k. Probably still manageable (at least just for the urls). But I am interested in general. I would like my pipeline not to be constrained by memory and be more streaming oriented (start processing as soon as possible). I've now used 'group by' with a random key. What would be the advantage of using _reshuffle_?

Comment: Note that it's "materialization on temporary persistent storage", not "loading the entire data in memory", so data size is not a concern unless we're talking about eg. hundreds of GB in a pipeline that would otherwise have been processing only a few MB. The advantage of using reshuffle is that it is semantically transparent and only affects performance but not *what* is computed: it doesn't perform windowing, doesn't change the triggering strategy of the output, and doesn't drop data according to your trigger etc., while GBK is an actual aggregation operation and it does all of these things.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using beam.Reshuffle? It seems like this isn't well documented but I hear from some good sources that this is what you should use.

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/other/reshuffle/